# render builder json not rendering correctly

Tags: json, grails

I have the following:

```
render(builder: "json") {
   template(message:'hello', dateCreated:'someDate') {
      resources {
          resource(id: "123")
          resource(id: "456")
      }
   }
}
```

I'm getting the following in Firebug:

```
{"template":{"message":"hello","dateCreated":"someDate"}}
```

I can't figure out why I am not getting the resources collection.

Answer (score 1):

I usually just create a map with the structure that I want and then render it as JSON.

```
import grails.converters.JSON
def data = [template: [message: 'hello', dateCreated: 'someDate', resources: [[id: "123"], [id:"456"]]]]
render data as JSON
```

Not sure if that's the exact structure you're looking for but it provides you with

```
{"template":{"message":"hello","dateCreated":"someDate","resources":[{"id":"123"},{"id":"456"}]}}
```

You can see an example here:

http://manbuildswebsite.com/2010/01/29/rendering-json-using-grails-part-1-collections-testing-and-the-jsonbuilder/

Comment: I realize that is possible.  But my question is, why does my code not work.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect `resource(id: "123")` is being resolved as a call to the `g.resource` taglib. Can you try the following instead (or rename resource to something else):

```
render(builder: "json") {
   template(message:'hello', dateCreated:'someDate') {
      resources {
          'resource'(id: "123")
          'resource'(id: "456")
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't even think about that Don.  I'll give that a shot when I work back to that part of the code and update you after.  Thanks.

Comment: @Gregg you're welcome, I'll be curious to see if my hunch was right